# Container needed for C++

Tags: c++, containers

I need a container (like array)for integers in such a way that given x and y and z ,which has to be inserted between x and y it will be possible to insert z between them.And given x and y ,get if x is placed left to the y.

Comment: What is the rule that determines that `z` must be placed between `x` and `y`?

Comment: Ah, I think now I understand. You basically want put elements in some arbitrary order and then you want to quickly ask if `a` comes before `b`? So that the sequence of elements defines and ordering that can be used to compare elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use an [`std::set<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/). It will always keep your elements ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, use vector.

Something like this.

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(x);
v.push_back(y);
vector<int> :: iterator it = v.begin();
v.insert(it + 1, z);
```

Have a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/

Comment: If I have vector of size 100 .And Given x,y and z it will be not effectively to insert z in such a way .... Because I`ll need to run until I find iterator to x - it.And only then make insert - insert(it+1,z)